# Using nested while loops for subtags (PHP script generating a dynamic XML file)

Tags: php, xml, loops, while-loop

I've just started to learn PHP & XML, so bear with me!
I need to generate a dynamic XML file from a MYSQL database using a PHP script.

I want my output to look like this:

```
<Post>
  <Title>
  <Tags>
    <Tag>
    <Tag>
    <Tag>
  <Date>
  etc.
</Post>

<Post>
</Post>
```

Now I've successfully made a query and used it in While-Loop. But I actually have a second query that needs to be implemented. The first query handles all tags such as *Title*, *Date* and all the other tags that are on the same level. But for *Tags*, I need subtags that require a second query as well.

Now, how do I create a nested while loop that inserts data into *Tags*? The problem is that every post has several tags (or just one) and I don't know how it's possible for the php script to "go into" *Tags*, insert the tag-elements defined by the second query and then goes back one level and continues executing the first query (would be *Date* here).

Maybe I don't need a second while loop, I don't know!

Comment: What you're asking for is also known as the *serialization of (relational) database data as XML*. This is tremendously big topic, when you start to dig into that with the search engine of your choice you can find a lot from bad written, outdated tutorials, well made libraries for the job, documentation of database vendors about their products and even scientific papers. Your question can be greatly improved if you show what you've tried so far (even if the code does not work as you want it to) so it's more clear at which point you're actually stuck. Otherwise, a big, big, big topic you ask.. .

Comment: Thank your for your answer! I now added my code. I'm just not sure how to proceed :/

Comment: And perhaps not so sure as well about what to ask.  What hinders you to add more and more loops over and over again? Also, have you considered to make use of an XML library to create the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with nesting while loops other than the possible performance problems that come with larger data sets (because you, if I understand you correctly, have a query for `<tags>` for each `<post>`).

Just nest  your loops somehow like that (if you go with the query for each tag):

```
<?php
$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM posts");

$xmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
$xmlBody .= "<XML>";

while($post = $result -> fetch_array()) {

   $xmlBody .= "<post>";

   $xmlBody .= "<title>" . $post['title'] . "</title>";

   // ....

   $xmlBody .= "<tags>";

   $tags_result = $mysqli -> query("
       SELECT * 
       FROM tags 
       WHERE id='" . $post['id'] . "'
   ");

   while($tag = $tags_result -> fetch_array()) {
     $xmlBody .= "<tag>" . $tag['tag'] . "</tag>";
   }

   $xmlBody .= "</tags>";

   // More Info (for example date)....

   $xmlBody .= "</post>";

}
```

This is written completely blind, but I hope it illustrates what you want to achieve quite good. Instead of doing this you should probably look into using a prewritten API for XML like [SimpleXML](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). Also, it is probably possible to do this in a single MySQL query using [JOIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

@hakre That is what I thought, I was just giving an example for what he described. I would have commented that an example would be helpful if I could (not enough reputation).

**Update:**

I updated the code sample above. Sorry for the mistake I made in using this syntax: `$post -> title`. This would only apply if `$post` was an object, which it isn't.

For clarification, I used the object-oriented syntax in the MySQL queries and fetching. See [this](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) for reference.

Comment: Thanks! While your solution looks good, I do have some troubles understanding the basic syntax here. I've learned it only way, and that is via writing out the tags in the xml body. I now have a feeling my code is kinda bad...

Comment: No, your code is not bad at all. I'm just used to writing everything as compact as possible. I see that you need to have all your XML in one variable, so I will edit my example above and make the syntax a bit more readable for you.

Comment: I made a mistake (see the updated answer above). What I am basically doing, is constructing the `$xmlBody` variable inside of the `while` loops. For the second while loop, (while I can only _guess_ that this somehow represents your DB structure) I use the ID provided by each entry in the first query to query the database for each tag with that ID every time the outer `while` loop is executed.